# is there such list control in c++

Tags: c++, sql, datasource, listcontrol

I am using MFC.
I need a control just like listControl, it has such functions:

```
MyListControl mylistControl = new MyListControl();
mylistControl.setDataSource(...);
mylistControl.setSQLStatement("select a, b, c, d from table where a > 3");
```

and system will have a listControl which is populated with the data from database, and generate the corresponding columns a, b, c, d respectively.
If there is such kind of a control, please tell me.
If you have any suggestion, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: C++ itself has no GUI capabilities - you need to specify what platform and libraries you are using.

Comment: @the_drow: not sad at all. If there was, you'd be stuck using it. As it is you can have any one of a multitude of GUIs... hmm maybe we should standardise on QT after all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your platform you will need different code.  You will need to use a GUI framework, there is no GUI standard library in the C++ language.

If you want Windows and C++ you can use [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e(VS.71).aspx)'s [CListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78(VS.80).aspx), but this is not as powerful as you mentioned and you need to do your own data loading.

The more portable way would be to use [Qt](https://qt.nokia.com/products) and it's [QListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) [QSqlDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html) classes.

Comment: It's also worth noting that wxWidgets has the powerful wxGrid control